# Slow Wi-Fi speed with Broadcom BCM4321 on 22.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, broadcom, lts

I'm new using Ubuntu, so something I'm still learning, so I'm having a few issues with my Wi-Fi connection.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, made all configs and I had to install firmware-b43 to get Wi-Fi working, but this only solves the Wi-Fi not working issue, because now I'm facing a really slow Wi-Fi speed. When i use cabled, I get 150Mpbs easily, but when I use wireless I just got 10Mbps maximium

I've tried change power save option, change the 5 GHz band, update and upgrade everything possible, I've followed a lot of tutorials but nothing seems to solve the problem!

I'm using a 2008 iMac (8,1) that I'm trying to make it useful again.

[image: iwconfig and lspci]

Comment: have a look at https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/15811

Comment: I already did all this, but nothing seems to work.